# Can I initialize 2 Flutter Web apps?

Tags: flutter

I have a site, mysyte.com, where I have two Flutter apps, one in the root folder mysite.com/ and the other at mysite.com/second/.

I wanted to know if by going directly to mysite.com/second/, instead of only uploading the second app, is it possible to upload also the app in root folder?

**So if I switch from the second to the first via url_launcher I don't have to wait for flutter to load...**

I don't have much web skills so maybe it's a problem there.

I searched the documentation and online but couldn't find anything